# Android studio flutter new project creating problem

Tags: flutter

When I am opening the new flutter project in android studio , It is showing an error is"Project location already exist C: User/AndroidStudioProjects".

Comment: Try to change the project location.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a subfolder where you are going to save the project.

So your folder path should be like:

```
C:\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyNewProject
```

Note: you can change `MyNewProject` whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

create a subfolder per each project in `AndroidStudioProjects` or you can change the whole path